# Passing Code as String

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, vbscript

I have created a Web API that will receive Input from Jquery and will use this input to dynamically alter a string that's stored in a resource file.

This String happens to be an almost complete piece of vbscript code that I plan on passing back down to my website.

My problem is that the resource automatically "stringifies" the Code and the output is flooded with escape characters which renders it completly unusable as actual code.

Is there a way to store the code in a way that makes escape strings unneccesary while still enabling me to alter it similiar to "if it were a string" and pass it down to my Website?

The goal is to then use Jquery/Javascript to make this code into an actual vbscript file and let the user download it.

As per request here some Code.

```
public string GetDeployment(Deployment deployment)
{
  string vbs = Resource1.vbs;

  vbs = vbs.Replace("%environment%", deployment.SystemKind);
  vbs = vbs.Replace("%platform%", deployment.PlatformKind);
  vbs = vbs.Replace("%application%", deployment.ApplicationName);
  vbs = vbs.Replace("%config", deployment.ConfigInfix ?? "Null");
  vbs = vbs.Replace("%subFolder%", deployment.subFolder ?? "Null");

  return vbs;
}
```

This method alters the vbscript depending on the Input. The API itself receives a JSON with Data for all the properties of deployment.

```
public class DeploymentController : ApiController
{
private DeploymentRepository DeploymentRepository;

public DeploymentController()
{
  DeploymentRepository = new DeploymentRepository();
}

[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]Deployment deployment)
{
  return DeploymentRepository.GetDeployment(deployment);
}
}
```

Comment: If the goal is just to return the file, then the escape characters won't matter. In fact you will probably want to keep them.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply download the file?  Either with a direct link, or a link to something that builds/modifies/whatever the file and then returns that?

Comment: Well, they obviously make it so that everything is one giant string. As soon as i remove the closing and ending " all the things that are supposed to be a string are not a string anymore and linebreaks are still represented by their escape characters (which isn't valid vbscript).

Comment: do you have an actual example of a: what your jquery that invokes the http request looks like, b: what your http request is sending as data, c: what your web api method looks like (the broad gist), and d: what **exactly** your web api method is receiving as input?